# Why is Jest throwing me Syntax Errors about Regular Expressions in vm2?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

First, of all, I'm new to the world of JS so please bear with me if this has already been fixed somewhere. I've spent the better part of a week trying to figure out the issue while going through forums and changing my jest configuration in my `package.json` but have had no luck.

We've been using `jest 26.6.3` until recently, and have been forced to migrate to the most recent update. As expected, not everything ran smoothly. We are currently getting the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    /app/node_modules/vm2/lib/bridge.js:1
    (function(global) {"use strict"; const exports = {};/app/node_modules/vm2/lib/bridge.js
                                                        ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

And I have no idea of what could be causing it. After digging around for some time, I've tried a few things but have had no luck. We have been using `jest` as-is out of the box and have never had a problem.

Node version is `20.2.0`.

**What I've tried:**

Now, I know that the testRunner and testEnvironment have both changed but after tweaking the config in `package.json` so `vm2` gets ignored (as follows), I keep getting the same error.

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "vm2.+\\.js$":"babel-jest",
      "\\.[tj]sx?$": "babel-jest",
      "/app/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js" : "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules\/(?!vm2)"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
...
}
```

Comment: There's an extraneous pathname in the code. Since it begins with `/`, it looks like a regular expression.

Comment: Hmmmm... but that code is not written by me. Some module builds that code on the fly when I run tests.

Comment: Something is wrong there, it's generating invalid code.